# Read data from image and crop certain part of image in node js

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, automation, ocr

My Client has requirement that user will upload image using that image i have to read data and crop some part of image. I am able to get read data from image using [tesseract.js](https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/) node module. Cropping part is also done it only work form some image not working for all images. below code to get data form images.

```
const Tesseract = require("tesseract.js");

Tesseract.recognize("./pancard.jpg", "eng", {
  logger: m => console.log(m)
}).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
  console.log(text);
});
```

For cropping image i am using sharp node module. below code basically resize image after resizing image its crop particular data.

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
sharp("./pancard.jpg")
  .resize(500, 300, {
    fit: sharp.fit.fill
  })
  .toFile("./pancard_new.jpg", (err, info) => {
    sharp("./pancard_new.jpg")
      .extract({ left: 35, top: 220, width: 180, height: 28 })
      .toFile("./pancard_new2.jpg", function(err) {});
  });
```

Above code working fine for below image i am able to get signature of that particular images. 
[image]

but same code not working for below image.
[image: Other image]

Basically i want to crop signature from that images. If someone have idea how to start from where to start to do above task please help me out.

Note*: Images are from google.

Comment: Images cointain personal Data of Real People. Please Blur Personal Identifiable Data.

Comment: @AbhikSarkar Images are already present on google.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to the image, with sharp, you can provide a viewbox to crop the image, but if the image provided is rotated, your code won't work for the first image as well. I think you need some kind of ml driven library for your use case like opencv, or set the viewbox big enough to capture the signature.

Answer (score 0):

If the signature panel on the Indian government ID is always in the same place, would it not be easier to just always crop the same viewbox? Rather than trying to detect the viewbox. That would be my MVP, if it needs to be dynamic later then it needs to be some computer vision library that is able to differentiate the signature from the rest of the ID.